# My kitchen faucet jumps, sputters and stops and squeals when water temperature reaches straight hot

Tags: water, faucet

Faucet and supply lines are 18 months old.  About a month ago, the faucet started jumping but only when on straight hot water and when the water temperature is probably close to 130 degrees.  It’s one of those newer models with the pull down sprayer.  Right after it jumps and water stops I can hear high pitched squeal.
Is there a washer inside the faucet that maybe softens and expands to restrict flow when it gets to hot?
When it jumps and squeals, I turn it off and immediately turn it back on at still a warm temp but not quite so hot and it works fine.  New Dishwasher on same valve and doesn’t appear to have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the anti-scald feature is working as designed. *i.e.* it's not SUPPOSED to let you burn yourself with excessively hot water, and the operation is as designed.

Dishwashers are not intended to operate with hands in them, so they normally have no anti-scald feature, and indeed may have a supplementary heater to raise the temperature even more for sanitizing.

Perhaps your hot water temperature has changed slightly, if this "just started happening" after 17 months.